How to do 80-bit floating point arithmetic with the Aarch64 architecture?
To give more context to what I asked in the title: I'm using VS C++, and I need to read an 80-bit floating point number from memory and format it into a human-readable form. I can somewhat do it for the Intel x64/x86 architecture, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it for Aarch64.
PS. For x64, I was able to do it in assembly by converting the 80-bit long double to double using this function:
; RCX = points to `long double` to convert from
; RDX = points to `double` to convert to

FLD     tbyte ptr [RCX]
FSTP    qword ptr [RDX]
ret

And then by printing the converted double value. It loses some precision, but that's OK.

Is that the only architecture you need it for? Otherwise you better follow the IEEE spec an interpret the bit pattern "manually".

@EugeneSh. I need to compile this binary for x86/x64/arm64. Hmm, yeah, that could be one option. I didn't want to complicate it too much if there's an easier option.

That is the easy option.

AFAIK Aarch64 doesn't have 80-bit registers and doesn't support any x87 instructions. You can load 10 bytes and convert them yourself, the x87 layout is rather simple.

Correct.  AArch64 has no hardware support for 80 bit floats.  You'll have to implement any sort of conversion in software.

Software libraries to handle this are not hard to find, e.g. here: https://github.com/SDL-Hercules-390/SoftFloat


I need to read an 80-bit floating point number from memory and format it into a human-readable form. I can somewhat do it for the Intel x64/x86 architecture, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it for Aarch64.

Try SoftFloat library, it has floatx80_to_float32,  floatx80_to_float64 and floatx80_to_float128. Detect the native format, act accordingly.
#include "softfloat.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    void* (*processFloatx80)(floatx80 fx80);
} FloatProcessor;

void* processFloatx80_to_float64(floatx80 fx80) {
    float64_t* result = (float64_t*)malloc(sizeof(float64_t));
    
    if (result != NULL) {
        *result = floatx80_to_float64(fx80);
    }
    return result;
}

void* processFloatx80_to_float32(floatx80 fx80) {
    float32_t* result = (float32_t*)malloc(sizeof(float32_t));
    
    if (result != NULL) {
        *result = floatx80_to_float32(fx80);
    }
    return result;
}

void* processFloatx80_to_float128(floatx80 fx80) {
    float128_t* result = (float128_t*)malloc(sizeof(float128_t));
    
    if (result != NULL) {
        *result = floatx80_to_float128(fx80);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    ...

    floatx80 fx80;
    FloatProcessor processor;

    #if defined(__FLOAT128__)
    processor.processFloatx80 = processFloatx80_to_float128;
    #elif defined(__aarch64__) || defined(__arm__) || defined(__x86_64__)
    processor.processFloatx80 = processFloatx80_to_float64;
    #else
    processor.processFloatx80 = processFloatx80_to_float32;
    #endif

    ...
}


What release of SoftFloat is this? 3e mentions floatx80 but I don't find any definition for it. There are many softfloat libraries around so you should mention the one you used in the answer.
